# IOS Distribution type can't be selected

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Im new to iOS development, I was wondering why the 3rd option on Distribution for Business
 and Eduction is disabled. I can't find any resources to explain it.

[image]

Comment: You need to complete the paid agreement and all required information under "tax and banking" including having a bank account recorded.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks we will process that part, btw, our account  is not enterprise, does it also cause the reason?

Comment: No.  Enterprise accounts *cannot distribute B2B apps*. Only company and personal memberships can.

Comment: ok thanks @Paulw11 Ill note that. currently our agreements still in processing status

Comment: I was recently unable to submit a B2B app even though I had done so in the past because there was no bank account registered on our account; Adding one fixed it; The requirement for a bank account seems to be a recent requirement